# Is there a way to apply hue ONLY to lower part of PairGrid in seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn

I was wondering if it was possible to apply hue to only the lower part of a seaborn `PairGrid`.

For example, say I have the following figure:
[image]

For what I need to present I'd like to keep the density plots on the diagonal, the overall scatter plots on the upper (with printed correlation coefficients above them which I know how to do), but on the lower I want to split the points up by hue just to show my audience what happens if we do subset the data.

I thought about just finding out the correlations for the upper, doing a hue plot and just changing all of the markers in the upper plots to the same colour, but then I lose the densities on my diagonal.

Does anybody know if my problem is possible?

Current code I'm using is

`ff = sns.PairGrid(test2,vars=['OzekePower','Power0','Power1','Power2'],palette="husl")
ff.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
ff.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)
ff.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)`

So what I'm hoping for is something like
`ff.map_lower(sns.scatterplot,hue='species')`
but this yields an error.

EDIT - I can do it if I leave the diag and upper blank and assign to the empty plots individually but this seems a lot more lengthy.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `PairGrid` does not have a `map_dataframe` method, which could otherwise be used to include further dataframe columns into the mapping. Kind of a hack to obtain `hue` only in the lower part of the `PairGrid` is to leave the `hue` argument out in the `PairGrid` creation, and fill the grid where no hue is desired.
Then manually set the required parameters for the `hue` manually to the grid and finally call `map_lower`, which will then see the grid as if it had `hue` specified from the start.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("iris", cache=True)

g = sns.PairGrid(df)

g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)

g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)

# Now set parameters needed for `hue`
g.hue_vals = df["species"]
g.hue_names = df["species"].unique()
g.palette = sns.color_palette("husl", len(g.hue_names))
# Then map lower
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Trying to run your code I get the following error when attempting to map to the lower: `color = self.palette[k] if kw_color is None else kw_color` `IndexError: list index out of range` Any idea what is going on?

Comment: No. Are you running precisely the code from above? Or did you use other data?

Comment: Interesting, it works with the code you provided but not my own dataframe. Could it be because there are some nan values in my dataframe?

Comment: Indeed, the column used as hue should not contain any nans. Other data can be nan. I suppose the problem is rather that you have more hue levels than colors in the palette. Will update the answer.

Comment: Yes I think that may be the case. I have 25 hue values which I think is why the code is breaking

Comment: When I run this exact code, I get blue dots on both the upper and lower portions of the figure.  Seaborn 0.11.1