# Seaborn increase title fontsize in custom pairgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following plot in seaborn which I managed to create using SO help (mainly [Is there a way to apply hue ONLY to lower part of PairGrid in seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554925/is-there-a-way-to-apply-hue-only-to-lower-part-of-pairgrid-in-seaborn/54556442#54556442)) but I am currently stuck in the part where I have to increase the font size of my legend Title. How would one go about it?
My code for the plot is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')

my_plot = sns.PairGrid(df)
my_plot = my_plot.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, shade=True)
my_plot = my_plot.map_lower(sns.regplot, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.3})
my_plot.hue_vals = df["species"]
my_plot.hue_names = df["species"].unique()
my_plot.palette = sns.color_palette("Set2", len(my_plot.hue_names))
my_plot = my_plot.map_upper(sns.scatterplot).add_legend(title='Species', fontsize= 20, title_fontsize=25)
```

[image]

But this does not work unfortunately, only the legend increases the font but not the title.
I went down this rabbithole: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8699 and if I understood correctly the title_fontsize should now be available. Also according to the documentation that I can see here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html

Am I understanding something wrong here? I am not so sure that my assumption that add_legend method of seaborn can take the same arguments as the legend method of matplotlib (please correct me if I am wrong as my understanding of seaborn method inheritance is kinda weak...)

I would be more than happy with any other suggestions as to how I would go about modifying the legend elements by using something different than add_legend or with a more matplotlib focused approach.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html) `add_legend` takes the arguments `legend_data, title, label_order`. So `title_fontsize` is not one of them.

Comment: Alright! How does the fontsize increase then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some searching in the code for add_legend, I found this part:

```
title = self._hue_var if title is None else title
        try:
            title_size = mpl.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] * .85
        except TypeError:  # labelsize is something like "large"
            title_size = mpl.rcParams["axes.labelsize"]

        # Set default legend kwargs
        kwargs.setdefault("scatterpoints", 1)

        if self._legend_out:

            kwargs.setdefault("frameon", False)

            # Draw a full-figure legend outside the grid
            figlegend = self.fig.legend(handles, label_order, "center right",
                                        **kwargs)
            self._legend = figlegend
            figlegend.set_title(title, prop={"size": title_size})
```

And based on my understanding (which is limited granted) of this code I assume that the only way to do it is to change the `mpl.rcParams["axes.labelsize"]` parameters. And this works, but has the consequence that also the axis labels change in size:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
mpl.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 20

my_plot = sns.PairGrid(df)
my_plot = my_plot.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, shade=True)
my_plot = my_plot.map_lower(sns.regplot, scatter_kws={'alpha':0.3})
my_plot.hue_vals = df["species"]
my_plot.hue_names = df["species"].unique()
my_plot.palette = sns.color_palette("Set2", len(my_plot.hue_names))
my_plot = my_plot.map_upper(sns.scatterplot).add_legend(title='Species', fontsize= '12')
```

This is not ideal to my mind as it changes also unintended parts to the chart.

[image]