# Applying hue to lower or upper part of PairGrid in seaborn 0.11.2

Tags: python, seaborn, scatter-plot

A solution to this problem was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554925/is-there-a-way-to-apply-hue-only-to-lower-part-of-pairgrid-in-seaborn).  However, for a more recent version of seaborn (0.11.2), it doesn't work, instead yielding a scatter plot in a single color.

Here is the previously proposed solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("iris", cache=True)

g = sns.PairGrid(df)

g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)

g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot)

# Now set parameters needed for `hue`
g.hue_vals = df["species"]
g.hue_names = df["species"].unique()
g.palette = sns.color_palette("husl", len(g.hue_names))
# Then map lower
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot)

plt.show()
```

which yields:

[image]

Can anyone propose a solution to this problem that will work for Seaborn 0.11.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I would do this

```py
df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.PairGrid(df, hue="species")
g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot)
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, hue=None)
g.map_diag(sns.kdeplot, hue=None)
g.add_legend()
```

[image]

You could do it the other way, only assigning `hue` in the `map_upper` call. But it would be tricker to get the legend right.